# Android - Display image to fit width of device

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am developing an android app thap show some photos in a listview.
This is layout for each item in listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exam_page_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My listview displays

[image]

I want to display imageview that fits the width of device. (fit width only)

[image]

Could you give me suggestion or have any idea to resolve this problem ?

Comment: `android:layout_width="match_parent`?

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: provide the code of your listview if `match_parent` doesn't work with you

Comment: Either you can use android:layout_width="match_parent" or android:scaleType="fitXY" which stretches both height and width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<ImageView
android:id="@id/imgview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


android:adjustViewBounds = "true"
```

Will help when your images are larger than the imageview. It will not strech the image but will shrink it.

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

For times when your image is smaller than imageview, it will strech the image to the width of its parent.